# Content available through AJAX

Tags: ajax, c1-cms

I wonder if it's possible to create a lazy loading content website, which loads the content as you scroll down, or when it becomes visible.

I do not think there is anything by default, so guess you would have to create handlers(ashx or webAPI) to provide the content (localized), but I do not know how to query for a specific PagePlaceholderContentElements.Content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to access the content was not that hard, missing a *using* and class name typo were the problems.

```
 XhtmlDocument.Parse(c.Get<Composite.Data.Types.IPagePlaceholderContent>().First().Content)
```